# Sharing file using vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, excel-2013, file-sharing

I have an excel file and a form created in visual studio 2013. Using the form the data is inserted in excel file. Now, this file and form will be used by several users at the same time through a common drive. Now, the problem is when I share the file and they enter data in the form and click submit button which transfers the data from the form to excel, an error occurs:

"unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click continue, the application will ignore the error and attempt to continue. If you click quit, the application will close immediately. Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"

**EDIT:** This is my code:

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\test.xlsx")
    'xlApp.Visible = True
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    xlworksheet1 = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    xlWorkSheet.Unprotect()
    Dim iRow As Long
    iRow = 1
    With xlWorkSheet
        Do While .Cells(iRow, 2).value <> ""
            .Cells(iRow, 2).activate()
            iRow = iRow + 1
        Loop
        .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.t1.Text
        .Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.t2.Text
        .Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.t3.Text
        .Cells(iRow, 7).Value = Me.t4.Text
        .Cells(iRow, 10).Value = Me.t5.Text
        .Cells(iRow, 13).Value = Me.t6.Text
        .Cells(iRow, 14).Value = Me.t7.Text
        .Cells(iRow, 20).Value = Me.t8.Text
    End With

    Me.t1.Text = ""
    Me.t2.Text = ""
    Me.t3.Text = ""
    Me.t4.Text = ""
    Me.t5.Text = ""
    Me.t6.Text = ""
    Me.t1.Focus()


    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    xlWorkSheet.Protect()
    xlWorkBook.Save()
    xlWorkBook.Close()

End Sub
```

How do I correct this? Please help!

Comment: If only there was a way for us to know what the relevant code is.

Comment: @jmcilhinney the code is normal entering of data in excel through the windows application form.

Comment: If you refuse to provide the code then you're not likely to get much help.  Your choice.

Comment: It appears that you need a database to store the data, not Excel. There are many free databases available, such as SQL Server Express (seeing as you are using MS technology).

Comment: Without  using SQL, is there anyway? Because they don't want me to use any other stuff other than excel and visual studio

Comment: Sorry @jmcilhinney I have provided my code. Please help!